# Install CakePHP Plugin and Helper via Composer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, composer-php

I want to install the following plugin and helper via Composer:

```
https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit
https://github.com/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper
```

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "cakephp/debug_kit",
            "version": "2.0",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "origin/2.0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper",
            "version": "2.1",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "origin/2.1"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper": "2.1.*",
    "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.0"
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "DebugKit": "/cakephp/debug_kit/",
        "TwitterBootstrap" : "/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper"
    }
}
}
```

The packages are successfully installed at Vendor/cakephp/debug_kit and Vendor/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper

My issues lies in how to I load them in CakePHP.  I have the following in my bootstrap.php:

```
require APP . 'Vendor/autoload.php';
```

When I attempt to load the Plugin after requiring the autoload with:

```
CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');
```

It can not be found.  Similar results with loading the helper in my AppController.php with

```
public $helpers = array('TiwtterBootstrap');
```

I am a newbie to Composer and am likely missing something simple or just not grasping how to properly load them from the Vendors folder.

Answer (score 10):

Everything you have done is correct, you just need to add an extra section to instruct composer where to install your plugin. Note the extra "installer-paths" sections
, it needs to point to the relative path where you want you plugin be installed.

```
        {
          "minimum-stability": "dev",
          "config": {
              "vendor-dir": "vendors"
          },
          "extra": {
            "installer-paths": {
              "app/Plugin/DebugKit": ["cakephp/debug_kit"],
            }
          },
          "require" : {
            "php": ">=5.4",
            "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*"
          }
        }
```

Comment: I added the following (No app folder because all work is done with what would be app as my CakePHP core lives elsewhere and webroot/index.php is adjusted as appropriate):  <br />    <pre><code>"extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "Plugin/DebugKit": ["cakephp/debug_kit"],
            "View/Helper": ["loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper"]
        }
    }</pre></code>  <br />I wiped out everything previously created including composer.lock and re-ran the install. Same results. Nothing in Plugins or View/Helper

Comment: the "extra" section worked for me but needed to remove the trailing comma after ["cakephp/debug_kit"]

Answer (score 0):

I was rushed this morning in my comment, here is the "extra" block I added to my composer.json:

```
    "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "Plugin/DebugKit": ["cakephp/debug_kit"],
        "Plugin/TwitterBootstrap": ["loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper"]
    }
```

Deleting my composer.lock in order to start over with the install, still didn't put the files into the Plugin folder.  However, even if I got that to work, I thought it would be possible for the system to recognize the plugins from the Vendor folder via the composer autoload and perhaps some magic from Cake.  That way I could just keep the entire Vendors folder out of my repository for this project and update my dependencies as needed.

I ended up solving my issue by just sym linking to these files from the Plugin folder and my system is recognizing the Plugins.